# QGIS Points in Polygon Crashes

Tags: qgis

I have a layer of points that are spread out in different areas.  I created a polygon layer for each area, and tried to count the number of points in each polygon using Vector > Analysis Tools > Points in Polygon.  QGIS 2.0.1 is crashing every time.  I have already checked and both layers are using the same CRS (WGS 84).
Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?
[image]

Comment: Are both layers shapefiles?

Comment: Yes, both layers are shapefiles